# Ancillary socket data, alignment problems?

Tags: c, sockets

In the source code of the ping from `freebsd`, I noticed this when the code is dealing with control data that contain `timestamp` from `SO_TIMESTAMP` socket option:

Here' example:

```
            #ifdef SO_TIMESTAMP
            if (cmsg->cmsg_level == SOL_SOCKET &&
                cmsg->cmsg_type == SCM_TIMESTAMP &&
                cmsg->cmsg_len == CMSG_LEN(sizeof *tv)) {
                /* Copy to avoid alignment problems: */
                memcpy(&now, CMSG_DATA(cmsg), sizeof(now));
                tv = &now;
            }
            #endif
```

What are the alignment problems author had in mind and why isn't it sufficient to just save a pointer to `CMSG_DATA(cmsg)`?

Is it important I copy the ancillary data myself when dealing with the same situation?

Full source code is here:([See docs](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sbin/ping/ping.c?revision=241852&view=co))

Comment: How about endianness, Is the timestamp guaranteed to stay within the same host ?

Comment: Look at the `CMSG_DATA` macro (I assume it is a macro because it is UPPERCASE), that might have some magic.

Comment: The timestamp isn't transfered on network. The kernel on local machine adds it to recieved packets.

Comment: @cdarke it's a POSIX macro for dealing with socket control data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmsg` is a `struct cmsghdr`, which is a variable length structure that consists of a few fields at the beginning, followed by arbitrary bytes starting at `cmsg_data`.  Since structure of the arbitrary bytes is not known at compile time, the place where the bytes start might not provide for the fields in the structure to be properly aligned. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment for some background information).

So what is happening here is that the expression in the `if` statement is checking what type of data the arbitrary bytes actually are, at runtime.  If the level, type, and length indicate that the data is a `struct timeval`, then the bytes are copied (via the `CMSG_DATA` macro) into a properly aligned structure on the stack.

Comment: Thanks. I knew how cmsg and CMSG_DATA works but I wasn't sure why was it necessary to copy it instead of using just a pointer